# Chrome dev tools with horrible performance

Tags: performance, google-chrome, debugging, reactjs, webpack

Lately I have been having trouble with debugging using Chrome dev tools. Once I open dev tools and start using the javascript debugger or the HTML inspector, every action will take at least a few seconds. Another developer with the exact same machine does not experience similar problems. I have tried reinstalling chrome and installing Chrome Canary, but the problem still remains the same. It did not use to be like this, and it is driving me mad, so that is why I am reaching out to the stack overflow community. Does anyone know any common reasons why dev tools would be performing so badly on a decent computer? Are there any settings I can try disabling, etc?

I am running Windows 10, and the client-side technology stack I am working with is based on React and Webpack with hot reload.

Comment: Check for resources usage. Hit SHIFT + ESC to open Task Manager inside chrome. Or open Menu > More Tools > Task Manager. Determine if there is some process/tab causing this behavior.

Also try to temporary disable your virus scanner and see if that works.

Comment: Have you tried removing source maps to see if that fixes the slowness? Also, try using an Incognito window.

Comment: com2ghz: Chrome seem to be using 30-50% cpu when I am messing around in dev tools, so either it is not using the full potential (and the error is not related to high CPU load), or it is just not utilizing multicore parallelization pontential. I have 2 cores with 4 logical cores.

robertklep: Neither seemed to make a difference, unfortunately.